# Как оптимизировать алгоритм изменения цвета градиента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow

У меня есть пара строчек кода, которая умеет менять цвет градиента на указанный, выглядит так:

```
fade = Im.open("path")

for i in range(fade.size[0]):
   for j in range(fade.size[1]):
       if fade.getpixel((i, j))[-1] != 0:
           fade.putpixel((i, j), (255, 255, 255, fade.getpixel((i, j))[-1]))
```

проблема в том, что такая конвертация - очень не оптимальная, занимает 10 секунд

Как это можно оптимизировать?

Comment: В глаза бросилось, что вы 2 раза вызываете эту функцию `fade.getpixel((i, j))`. Можно ее результат сохранить в переменную: `pixel = fade.getpixel((i, j))`. Для ускорения вычислений ищите способ распараллелить циклы.

Comment: может getdata, a потом цикл, но как обратно в image -- не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

numpy предоставляет классное решение

```
fade = Im.open(path)
        pix = np.array(fade)
        alpha = pix[:, :, 3]
        mask = alpha > 0
        pix[mask, 0] = 255
        pix[mask, 1] = 255
        pix[mask, 2] = 255
        fade = Image.fromarray(pix)
```